# What is the best way to define and use a large lookup set

Tags: lookup, list, static-resources

The problem seems so simple, but I was not able to this point to find a solution, even after hours of googling.

**Problem:**
We push external data into our Salesforce system and have hundreds of cities on our custom objects. We assign those cities to custom regions fitting our business needs. I would now like to have one central list of cities per region and be able to refer to that list in custom formulas.

**What I have tried so far:**
Custom List Setting, but this really seems to be more of a lookup tool in the other direction, i.e. if I provided a region, I could get the head sales rep or the population size or other information I would store there.
Long if lists in custom formulas, but that causes the inconstancy and will not be working going forward.

Help is much appreciated

Update:
Custom formula for "Region Field" would look something like this:

```
IF(city__c in [MY LIST TO DEFINE FOR REGION A]),'REGION A', 
IF(city__c in [MY LIST TO DEFINE FOR REGION B]),'REGION B', 
IF(city__c in [MY LIST TO DEFINE FOR REGION C]),'REGION C', 'No Region Assined')
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate to break this to you, but formulas can't do this. You would need to write a trigger, or Process Builder/Flow in order to get this effect. Formula fields can only use Hierarchy Custom Settings, and VLOOKUP formulas only work in Validation Rules.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76335/discussion-on-answer-by-sfdcfox-what-is-the-best-way-to-define-and-use-a-large-l).